Wifi menu not showing but card detected
I just installed ubuntu 24.04 and I have a wifi card (Aorus GC-WBAX200).
I don't have the wireless menu in the top right corner. And when I go to settings, I only see the wired connection.
When I run lshw -C network I get
*-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ                      //unclaimed
       description: Network controller
       produit: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:21:00.0
       version: 1a
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: cap_list
       configuration : latency=0
       ressources : mémoire:fcc00000-fcc03fff

When I run lspci | grep Network I get
21:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)

It looks like the card is recognized by the system, but I can't see or connect to any wifi network.

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

@waltinator Not really. I ran the script and got a ton of information, but that does not tell me why it is not working. The output doesn't mention the unclaimed information anywhere, and I still don't know why it is unclaimed

I think I installed my distro without the "proprietary" drivers. I had to reinstall for another reason, and I installed them this time. Now it works.
